# Can I link pagination of separate DT tables in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have two tables in Shiny generated with `DT::datatable()`. The tables have the same dimensions but come from different data frames and thus different columns (unlike the iris data below). The tables will be on the same page.

Can I link the two tables so that if I press the Next button (or page number) of one table, both tables change at the same time? That is, press Next moves both tables to the next page. Press 3 moves both tables to Page 3.

In the example below, I show both pagination controls for both tables but if I can link them it would be cleaner to show just the controls for the upper table.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5("Table 1"),
  DTOutput("table1"),
  h5("Table 2"),
  DTOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ],
      options = list(
        dom = '<"top" p>',
        pageLength = 6)
    )
  })
  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[iris$Species == "virginica", ],
      options = list(
        dom = "tp",
        pageLength = 6)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `dataTableProxy` along with `selectPage`. This is faster than rerendering the table after each button click:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5("Table 1"),
  DTOutput("table1"),
  h5("Table 2"),
  DTOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ],
      options = list(
        dom = '<"top" p>',
        pageLength = 6)
    )
  })
  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[iris$Species == "virginica", ],
      options = list(
        dom = "tp",
        pageLength = 6)
    )
  })
  
  table1Proxy <- dataTableProxy("table1")
  table2Proxy <- dataTableProxy("table2")
  
  observeEvent(input$table1_rows_current, {
    selectPage(table2Proxy, page = ceiling(max(input$table1_rows_current) / input$table1_state$length))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table2_rows_current, {
    selectPage(table1Proxy, page = ceiling(max(input$table2_rows_current) / input$table2_state$length))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @ismirehregal for your helpful answer. I liked the `dataTableProxy`. I just posted a [different but related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77442186/can-i-sort-two-separate-dt-datatables-in-r-shiny-by-sorting-on-a-column-from-one) on sorting the linked table. Perhaps you'll be able to suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `input$table1_rows_current` to link the two tables.  Then use the `displayStart` option to update the display in a table based on the display in the other table.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5("Table 1"),
  DTOutput("table1"),
  h5("Table 2"),
  DTOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    table1CurrentPage = 0,
    table2CurrentPage = 0
  )
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ],
      options = list(
        dom = '<"top" p>',
        displayStart = rv$table1CurrentPage,
        pageLength = 6)
    )
  })
  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[iris$Species == "virginica", ],
      options = list(
        dom = "tp",
        displayStart = rv$table2CurrentPage,
        pageLength = 6)
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table2_rows_current, {
    rv$table1CurrentPage <- input$table2_rows_current[1] - 1
  })
  observeEvent(input$table1_rows_current, {
    rv$table2CurrentPage <- input$table1_rows_current[1] - 1
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks @YBS for your helpful answer. I just posted a [different but related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77442186/can-i-sort-two-separate-dt-datatables-in-r-shiny-by-sorting-on-a-column-from-one) on sorting the linked table. Perhaps you know a solution?