# Can I sort two separate DT datatables in R Shiny by sorting on a column from one of the tables?

Tags: r, sorting, shiny, datatables, dt

I have two tables in Shiny generated with `DT::datatable()`. The tables have the same dimensions. They come from different data frames but some tables will share the same column names. The tables will be on the same page.

Can I link the two tables so if I sort the column of one table, it sorts the same column (by position or name) in the second table? To be clear, I mean sorting values in one column in ascending or descending order by clicking the small buttons next to the column header.

For example, if I sort the Sepal.Width column of one table, it will sort the same column of the other table. It should not matter whether the first or second table is sorted first.

I learned how to link pagination of the tables using `DT::dataTableProxy` from answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77438984/can-i-link-pagination-of-separate-dt-tables-in-r-shiny). I looked for options under `dataTableProxy` but did not see any that seemed related to sorting. (`ColReorder` seems to be for shifting the order of the columns across the table, not sorting a given column by ascending or descending value.)

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5("Table 1"),
  DTOutput("table1"),
  h5("Table 2"),
  DTOutput("table2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ],
      options = list(
        dom = '<"top" p>',
        pageLength = 6)
    )
  })
  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[iris$Species == "virginica", ],
      options = list(
        dom = "t",
        pageLength = 6)
    )
  })
  
  table1Proxy <- dataTableProxy("table1")
  table2Proxy <- dataTableProxy("table2")
  
  observeEvent(input$table1_rows_current, {
    selectPage(table2Proxy, page = ceiling(max(input$table1_rows_current) / input$table1_state$length))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table2_rows_current, {
    selectPage(table1Proxy, page = ceiling(max(input$table2_rows_current) / input$table2_state$length))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It would be great if you self-anwer your question with the RowGroup extension approach mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the suggestion from @ismirsehregal, here is my solution. I learned how to add and use the `RowGroup` extension for `datatable()`. Instead of two tables, I now have one.

I added a `group` column to define my main groups. The `orderFixed` option gives the group column highest priority so that subsequent sorting occurs within each group. I hid the grouping column via `columnDefs` as that suits my purpose.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("my_table"),
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDT({
    
    mtcars[1:10, 1:5] |> 
      mutate(group = c(rep("Group1", 5), rep("Group2", 5))) |> 
      datatable(
        extensions = 'RowGroup',
        options = list(
          dom = "t",
          order = list(1, "desc"),
          orderFixed = list(6, "asc"),
          rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 6), 
          # Hide the sorting column. Delete columnDefs to show column.
          columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = "group")),
          pageLength = 10
        ),
      )
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- c(
  "table.on( 'order.dt', function() {",
  "  var order = table.order();",
  "  if(order[0] !== undefined) {",
  "    var M = order.map(function(x) {return x.slice(0,2);});",
  "    var $table2 = $('#table2').find('table');",
  "    var table2 = $table2.DataTable().table();",
  "    table2.order(...M).draw();",
  "  }",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  splitLayout(
    DTOutput("table1"),
    DTOutput("table2")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output[["table1"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris[iris$Species == "setosa", ], callback = JS(callback))
  })
  
  output[["table2"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris[iris$Species == "versicolor", ])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can this be modified to also sort table1 by sorting table2? I created a `callback2` and changed all references of table2 to table1. As I suspected, when I sorted table2, it seemed to go into an infinite loop. I don't know JS.  Thank you for your effort.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work when I have the pagination linked as in my MWE.

Comment: I learned out how to use the RowGroup extension which provides an easier solution. Thank you again.